# Finding array element within a string C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, indexof

I've been looking for a way to check a string for elements of an array and if it contains one of those elements to return the indexOf it but i'm having trouble finding a way to do this. Most of my searches end up showing me way to find the indexOf an element in an array or something similar.

As a bit of background I'm trying to create a program that takes a string from user input, splits the words of the paragraph into an array, performs certain checks on them and changes them accordingly.

For instance if the current word starts with a consonant it finds the first vowel and moves all the letters in front of it to the end of the word. This is what I tried but it prints an index of 14 so clearly something is wrong:

```
char[] vowelsList = new char[] { 'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u' };

foreach (char vowel in vowelsList)
{
    if (currentWord.Contains(vowel))
    {
        int index = currentWord.IndexOf(vowel);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(index);
    }
}
```

currentWord is the word from the string from the user input that is currently being checked.

Any suggestion on different methods or keywords to try is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I apologise the code is actually fine, it was returning 1 and 4 because it was always receiving the input Hello and i was misinterpreting what was going on, I'm a bit of an idiot sometimes. I guess then my question would be how to get this code to only find the index of the first vowel but a poster has already stated how to do that, thank you all for the help and suggestions, most of which I have implemented.

Comment: To sum up - you just need to get first occurence (index) of element from given strings array (in this case `vowelsList`) in a input string? Or each first index of every string in array?

Comment: What is the value of `currentWord` in this example?

Comment: @pwas i just need to get first occurence of an element from given array in input string.

Comment: *prints an index of 14 so clearly something is wrong* - what's the value of `currentWord` in that case, and for which `vowel` it prints 14? I don't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: @fost "first occurence of an element from given array" did you mean **any element**?

Comment: You don't need to check twice if the word contain the char (`Contains` uses also `IndexOf`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use [`String.IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence in this instance of any character in a specified array of Unicode characters.

If no character is found, it returns `-1`.

```
var index = currentWord.IndexOfAny(vowelsList);
if (index >= 0)
{ 
    // do stuff
}
```

Note that, as stated on MSDN, this method performs an *ordinal* (culture-insensitive) search, where a character is considered equivalent to another character only if their Unicode scalar value are the same. To perform a *culture-sensitive* search, you would need to use an overload of `CompareInfo.IndexOf` method, where a Unicode scalar value representing a precomposed character.

Comment: Nice, never knew about this

Comment: holy @%$#, so simple. Didn't know about this either.

Answer (score 2):

[`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx) returns -1 if the string doesn't contain the vowel so just use that

> The zero-based index position of value if that character is found, or -1 if it is not.

```
int index = currentWord.IndexOf(vowel);    
if (index != -1)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(index);
}
```

And the obligatory linq answer:

```
vowelsList.Select(v => currentWord.IndexOf(v))
          .Where(idx => idx != -1)
          .ToList();
```

---

You can also half the number of iterations you have to make by using [`ToLower`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
char[] vowelsList = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

int index = currentWord.ToLower().IndexOf(vowel);    
if (index != -1)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(index);
}

vowelsList.Select(v => currentWord.ToLower().IndexOf(v))
          .Where(idx => idx != -1)
          .ToList();
```

---

If you just want the first index you can just turn your current code into an extension method as so

```
private int FirstIndexOfVowel(this string s)
{
    char[] vowelsList = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    foreach(char v in vowelsList)
    {
        int idx = s.ToLower().IndexOf(v);
        if(idx != -1)
            return idx;
    }
    return -1;
}


int idx = currentWord.FirstIndexOfVowel();
```

Linq version for first index only (returns null if none found)

```
vowelsList.Select(v => currentWord.ToLower().IndexOf(v))
          .FirstOrDefault(idx => idx != -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the efficiency tips and answering my real question before I even realised what that was :P.

Comment: @fost: for the sake of completeness, what was your real question?

Comment: @fost - No worries, I'm not sure which part of this is the bit that actually solved the problem but the `FirstIndexOfVowel` method here is basically what Groo's answer is doing

Comment: I think i've understood, use `Console.WriteLine` instead of `Console.Write` ;-)  (It was not index 14 but 1 + 4) You should also get familiar with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
   char[] vowelsList = new char[] {'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u'};

        foreach (char vowel in vowelsList)
        {
            if (currentWord.Contains(vowel))
            {
                int index = currentWord.IndexOf(vowel);

                Console.WriteLine(currentWord.Substring(index, currentWord.Length - index) +
                                  currentWord.Substring(0, index));
            }
        }
```

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for, my code is finding every instance of every vowel in a word but once I change that to only find the first vowel this code will do what I want the program to do. Ty

Comment: Happy for you mate :)

Answer (score 1):

> This is what I tried but it prints an index of 14 so clearly something
>   is wrong

You don't understand why it returns 14 even if the array doesn't contain so many characters? That means you expect that it returns the index of the char in the `char[]` but...

```
int index = currentWord.IndexOf(vowel);
```

returns the index of the char in the word.

This should work as expected, i use [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the index of the char in the array:

```
foreach (char vowel in vowelsList)
{
    if (currentWord.Contains(vowel))
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(vowelsList, vowel);
        //...
    }
}
```

Another approach is not to use `foreach` but a for-loop which already knows the index.

Comment: You'd be better off just using a for loop instead of foreach, then you have your index right there +1 if this is what op wants.

Comment: @Sayse: he's not iterating over `currentWord` elements.

Comment: @Groo - I never said he was

Comment: @Sayse: but I doubt OP needs the index of the `vowel` in the `vowelList`.

Comment: @Groo - Given the quote Tim has included its quite plausible that that is actually what the OP does want

Answer (score 1):

An example that will give you a nice and manageable overview of all vowels (or whatever your criteria for being in the array is):

```
var word = "Stupendous!";
char[] vowelsList = 
          new char[] { 'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u' };

// Get all matches in a word, along with their positions:
var allVowels = word.Select((chr, pos) => new {chr, pos})
                    .Where(match => vowelsList.Contains(match.chr));

var positionOfFirst = allVowels.First().pos;
```

**Update:** Tim Schmelter is probably right, so I`ll updated my answer to include the position of the characters in the array:

```
var allVowels = word
                 .Where(match => vowelsList.Contains(match))
                 .Select((chr, pos) => 
                           new {chr, pos, PosInArray = 
                                             Array.IndexOf(vowelsList, chr)});

var positionOfFirst = allVowels.First().PosInArray;
```

That last piece of code will return (for `allVowels`) an IEnumerable containing the following data:

```
{ {chr = u, pos = 2, PosInArray = 9}, 
  {chr = e, pos = 4, PosInArray = 3}, 
  {chr = o, pos = 7, PosInArray = 7}, 
  {chr = u, pos = 8, PosInArray = 9} }
```